# How do you nest panels in a class that already extends JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

The code I have is

```
public class IncomeStatementPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel costOfGoodSoldIncState = new JLabel("Cost of goods sold", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JLabel ebitIncState = new JLabel("EBIT", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JLabel deprecIncState = new JLabel("Depreciation", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    ...    

//I want to add more panels to this, but don't know the code to create them.

    public IncomeStatementPanel()
    {
        //Set grid layout for the panel
        setLayout(new GridLayout(14,2,0,0));



    }

}
```

Comment: Not extending `JPanel` might make the code easier. Also removing fields for labels (in normal circumstances you should be able to just slap them on the panel and forget about them).

Answer (score 2):

You can just add them like you normally would.

```
public class IncomeStatementPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel costOfGoodSoldIncState = new JLabel("Cost of goods sold", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JLabel ebitIncState = new JLabel("EBIT", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JLabel deprecIncState = new JLabel("Depreciation", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(); // Nothing special here
    ...    

    public IncomeStatementPanel()
    {
        //Set grid layout for the panel
        setLayout(new GridLayout(14,2,0,0));
        this.add(myPanel); // Or here. The "this." part is optional by the way.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your quick responses; they really helped :)